# SSAS measure display folders do not show up

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I'm developing a cube using the multidimensional model on the Sql Server 2014 Dev edition. Having quite a few measures in a single group I'm trying to organise them into display folders that doesn't work though for some reason. The defined display folders do not show up in any client - Visual Studio, SSMS, Excel, Power BI - you name it. Using VS I can see the defined folders in the properties window, on the translation tab, everywhere except the browser tab. And yes, the visibility attribute for the measures is set to True.

Please let me know if anybody came cross this and fixed.

Comment: To complete the previous post, if a measure or an attribute is translated, the display folder also needs a translation. In SSAS Tabular Translator, "TranslatedDisplayFolder" should be filled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out display folders will not appear unless you provide captions for the all added translations.